# IOS 8 UIDocumentPicker

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocumentinteraction

I have some questions regarding the UIDocumentPicker in iOS in terms of how can developer customize the content displaying to the user:
In the official document, it says there're 2 ways of presenting the Document Picker:

1. the menu of available storage the most recent used document picker
2. the most recent used doc picker.

I'm wondering if there's an option for user to choose what's the 'landing App Container'. For example, if I'm using Pages, I want the Pages folder in the iCloud drive to display first, then the user have the option to return to the main directory and choose other app containers.

Answer (score 0):

The API provides no facility to allow the calling app to pass any information to the document picker extension of the provider app. Furthermore, you can't explicitly specify which document picker (e.g. Dropbox/OneDrive/etc) you would like to open. So unfortunately, based on the published API docs and the Xcode betas so far, there is no way to do what you ask.